# Override retorna erro em ViewController secundária no Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou recebendo essa mensagem abaixo ao tentar fazer um swipe em uma celula de uma TableView. Lembrando que estou fazendo isso em um arquivo viewcontroller e não em uma tableViewController. É possível?

> Method does not override any method from ist superclass

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Voce só precisa override quando subclassing UITableView, como voce mesmo disse é  UIViewController, portanto é só retirar `override` e conectar o seu código (UIViewController) com um IBOutlet na sua UITableView

Comment: O problema é que ele não vai funcionar como eu quero sem a override.

Uma pergunta, posso criar a class separada para a tableview dentro de uma viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2):

Considerandoque você tenha uma instância de uma `UITableView` na sua `ViewController`, você precisa fazer tres coisas:

#### 1. Atribuir um delegate a sua instância de `UITableView`:

```
// considerando o ViewController onde tableView foi instanciado,
// implementa UITableViewDelegate
tableView.delegate = self
```

---

#### 2. Implemente o mesmo método que você está usando mas sem o `override`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

---

#### 3. Atribuir uma implementação ou criar uma extensão de `UITableViewDelegate` a sua classe:

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {}`

ou

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
  // implement me
}
```

---

#### Referências:

- [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview)
- [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)
- [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller)